# Как лучше разбивать классы Android-проекта?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как лучше всего разбивать классы по пакетам:
-по назначению

```
-database
-network
-reader
-ui
```

-по классам

```
-activities
-adapters
-fragments
-model
-utils
-widgets
```

Best-practices с Github рекомендуют разбивать так, как показано во втором примере, но из-за этого код приложения не будет модульным и такой код будет трудно переиспользовать (поправьте, если это не так). Как быть?

Можете также показать свои варианты.

Comment: Я думаю, вы можете разбивать так, как вам удобно - это не влияет ни на что, кроме вашего личного удобства. Тег [Android Studio] предназначен для вопросов, в которых решаются проблемы с работой этой IDE, ваш вопрос к таким не относится и тег этот лишний.

Answer (score 6):

Мне кажется ваши два варианта вполне сочетаются друг с другом:

```
-database
  -model
-network
  -model
  -request
-ui
  -activities
  -adapters
  -fragments
  -widgets
-utils
```

Я обычно как то так организую. Но вообще тема довольно холливарная.